# RETBleed Attack message on bootscreen in VirtualBox

Tags: security, virtual-machine, virtualbox

[image: a picture of the message]

Whenever i start virtual box
its gives me a message on the bootscreen
**RETBleed: WARNING: Spectre v2 mitigation leaves CPU vulnerable to RETBleed attacks, data leaks possible!**

is this a thing to worry about?
how can i fix it?